# Matlab bwlabel not connecting all components

Tags: matlab

I have this matrix:

```
ima =  [0 0 0 0 0;
    0 0 0 0 0;
    0 255 255 255 0;
    0 255 255 255 0;
    0 255 0 255 0;
    0 255 0 255 0;
    0 255 255 255 0;
    0 0 0 0 0;
    0 0 0 0 0];
[labels, number] = bwlabel(ima, 4);
labels
```

The result I get is:

```
labels =

 0     0     0     0     0
 0     0     0     0     0
 0     1     1     1     0
 0     1     1     1     0
 0     1     0     1     0
 0     1     0     1     0
 0     1     1     1     0
 0     0     0     0     0
 0     0     0     0     0
```

Why isn't the two zeros surrounded by the ones seen as a different component with a value of 2?

This is what I want:

labels =

```
 0     0     0     0     0
 0     0     0     0     0
 0     1     1     1     0
 0     1     1     1     0
 0     1     2     1     0
 0     1     2     1     0
 0     1     1     1     0
 0     0     0     0     0
 0     0     0     0     0
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only the values that are a `1` in your input matrix are considered as components to label. If you want the second output as you've shown, you would need to also apply `bwlabel` to the *inverse* of your matrix to label the `0` values.

```
[labels, number] = bwlabel(ima, 4);

% Compute the labels of the inverse
labels2 = bwlabel(~ima, 4);

% Combine the labels
labels = max(labels, labels2 + number + 1);
```

If you only want to label `0` values that are completely surrounded by `1`'s you can do something like this

```
[labels, number] = bwlabel(ima, 4);

% Find the 0's that are surrounded by 1's and label them
filled = imfill(ima, 'holes');
labels2 = bwlabel(filled & ~ima, 4);

% Combine the labels
labels(filled) = max(labels(filled), labels2(filled) + number + 1);
```

Comment: I will mark this as correct! Thanks. But the matlab example [link](https://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/bwlabel.html) did not use the `~` operator. What was the difference with that example from mines?

Comment: @Jam1 The `~`  is the [`not`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/not.html) operator and turns all  non-zeros to zero and all zeros to 1. Since `bwlabel` only operates on `1` values, `~` allows it to operate only on 0 values.

Comment: @Jam1 Why can't you?

Comment: Because `imfill` gives me exactly what I want. Professor said we should only use `bwlabel`